# Rails/Sendgrid Error: getaddrinfo: name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, sendgrid

I've all of a sudden started getting this error when creating users in my app.  Emails were working before I left for vacation, now I come back and this is what my tech support gives me!  Ugh.

So, I make a user, and I get redirected to my admin panel with the following error in a flash notice: `getaddrinfo: name or service not known`.  **The user isn't created.**

Looking at the logs, it looks like everything worked fine:

```
I, [2016-04-12T08:01:52.089647 #11555]  INFO -- : Started POST "/admin/user/new" for 72.238.202.193 at 2016-04-12 08:01:52 -0500
I, [2016-04-12T08:01:52.092114 #11555]  INFO -- : Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#new as HTML
I, [2016-04-12T08:01:52.092259 #11555]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vxhuTwXhQo6nYrskQcYH9W56Ej95LgzEbs8cnkjXQI4=", "user"=>{"company_id"=>"35", "username"=>"myuser@thedomain.com", "first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"User", "full_name"=>"Test User", "time_zone"=>"Central Time (US & Canada)", "email"=>"myuser@thedomain.com", "phone_number"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_sent_at"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_created_at"=>"", "sign_in_count"=>"0", "current_sign_in_at"=>"", "last_sign_in_at"=>"", "current_sign_in_ip"=>"", "last_sign_in_ip"=>"", "authentication_token"=>"", "enable_notifications"=>"1", "confirmation_token"=>"MBrmpsD6Wtf1VBrhtDyc", "confirmed_at"=>"", "confirmation_sent_at"=>"April 12, 2016 10:00", "unconfirmed_email"=>"myuser@thedomain.com", "terms_accepted"=>"1", "cancel_subscription"=>"0", "on_trial"=>"0", "is_account_owner"=>"1", "role_ids"=>["", "", "2"]}, "return_to"=>"https://www.myserver.com/admin/user?sort=created_at&sort_reverse=false", "_save"=>"", "model_name"=>"user"}
I, [2016-04-12T08:01:52.212064 #11555]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.6ms)
I, [2016-04-12T08:01:52.340343 #11555]  INFO -- : 
Sent mail to myuser@thedomain.com (9.3ms)
```

I've filtered the email address but, rest assured, it's a valid email.

I'm using EC2 to host my application, so I can't edit `/etc/resolv.conf` since any changes will be overridden.

I've run `nslookup` to make sure the server can find the domain MX records, which it does using the nameserver specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used a recommendation I ran across on another blog to use Ruby's version of `Resolv` instead of the libc library with Ubuntu.  So, I added the following line to an initializer: `require resolv-replace.rb`.

Now my error is a little more descriptive: `Hostname not known: smtp.sendgrid.net`, so I checked `config/environments/production.rb` and it turns out I had a trailing space at the end of my host line.  Removed it and all is working now!